# Nodejs PDF KIT, pdf file is in use by application

Tags: node.js, pdfkit

Sample code I have tried:

```
var PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');
var fs = require('fs');
var doc = new PDFDocument;

doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('test.pdf'));
doc.text('hello how r u');

var x= true;
doc.end();

while(x){
    console.log("***");
}
```

This code is not releasing the test.pdf and thereby I am not able to open the file.
How do I get the file released so that it can be used by rest of the application?

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been discussed on [github](https://github.com/devongovett/pdfkit/issues/265). The recommended way of doing something when writing to the stream is finished is to watch the finish event on the stream:

```
stream.on( 'finish', function() { ..... } );
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @rgettman The code -was- in the answer already. It was just badly formatted. Imo editing it was a much better solution than deleting it out of laziness. The link-only delete reason is solely for answers that consist of a link, and only of a link.